# Escape all characters in a string MarkdownV2 (python)

Tags: python, markdown

I happen to have trouble with a name "x" that has some special characters in it, now, this name shall be sent in a text with more stuff which uses MarkdownV2, however, this name "x" isn't avaiable for me, I dont know it, and I can't manually change it. Then, how can I escape all special characters in a string?

```
"""NAME: `this[]is.my!Name`
ID: `1012930239`"""
```

The name must use format, since "this[]is.my!Name" is external, so let's say I have it saved elsewhere as variable 'name', then

```
full_str = f"""NAME: `{name}`
ID: `{id}`"""
```

Answer (score 0):

to escape every character you put an r in front of the str to escape one character use a backslash

Comment: and, can I do something like fr'{name_x}'?

Comment: because I need the format also

Comment: I just learnt u actually can use "fr", though, the problem I am having with "r", is that it doesn't work with "(" open bracket, of course, because its not special in python string, but it is in markdownv2